# Android app that sends and receives data from pc

Tags: android, flash, remote-access

So ill do my best to explain. I'm wondering how easy (or hard) it would be to make an android app that talks/sends and receives data from a PC or mac, even more so with flash.

so for example, I first make a flash application on my PC / Mac, lets say it has a MovieClip of a square on the stage. That is all for that part. Next I make and android app that consists of one button. when I press that button (on the android app, on the phone) the square on the flash desktop application moves to the right or left by ten pixels.

so ultimately the mobile app is controlling the desktop flash application.

Iv searched and searched but I'm unsure of what keywords to really use to find what im looking for.

Can anybody shed some light on how difficult this is(if its possible), or any documentation / tutorials on this subject?

Answer (score 2):

The Bluetooth standard includes a profile called [Bluetooth HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device). If you write (or download!) an Android app that implements this profile, then connect your Android device to your PC, it basically becomes a Bluetooth mouse or keyboard. It would require no programming on the PC side, as both Windows and Mac support Bluetooth peripherals.

Implementing a network protocol on the device side is usually really low-level stuff. If your programming experience is only in flash, you'll probably find this tough going (you would likely learn a lot!). Luckily, there's the [Android HID](http://code.google.com/p/androhid/) library. I don't know how good it is (I just found it for this answer), but it looks done, so it would save you from having to do the most difficult parts.

Comment: Wow, they both look pretty good, I have knowledge in a few different languages although flash is my strongest, iv just got into bed but will have a proper look at these tomorrow, if I can just send keystrokes then I could acomplish my goal, thank for the response, ill update with my findings tomorrow

Comment: +1 I haven't used this either, but it appears to be bluetooth-only and requires a rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb to accomplish this, which is how many of the tethering apps get around carrier restrictions. Here are some sources:

Adblib is a "library to communicate with android devices with TCP over USB without requiring the Android SDK":
http://code.google.com/p/adblib/

Thread about Adb over USB:
http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/JsDTBimHpOA

adb itself:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

---

Here are some other links to some other Android USB topics:

http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbInterface.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, you really have given me lots to read and consider, I was really hoping to avoid any use of USB, I'm aiming at a wireless controller, but I will look into all of the above tomorrow and report back with findings, again thanks for response

Comment: No problem. ADB can actually use USB and/or bluetooth, and @Barend's response about Android HID looks like a great bluetooth solution. Good luck! :)

Comment: All these links are interresting, but is there no existing a concrete example with app pc side, and android side transmitting data by usb ? I'm still searching, but find nothing ...